# One site with 2 different physical paths (2 different subfolders)

Tags: iis, path

is it possible to that I can configure a site in IIS Manager with two different physical paths (2 subfolders)? 
Thank you ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only specify one path for the site, that is the path for loading the site's default document and configuration file (web.config) etc. But you can [add multiple virtual directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) for the website.

Comment: yeah I know, thank you for that. But if I login via cmd and enter "dir", I won't see the the virtual directory -.-
I only see the physical one.

Comment: This is [by design](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142853), you can workaround this by add a physical directory with the same name as the virtual directory.